# Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 Bootloop?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, odin, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1

I purchased a Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 in 2013, GT-N8010, Android 4.4 and recently, I had a problem- when it loaded, it said Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 and didn't load. I tried to factory reset it holding volumedown and power button, and it asked to go into ODIN mode- said a custom OS can damage the device etc. Then, on ODIN mode, it said:

ODIN MODE

PRODUCT NAME: GT-N8010

CUSTOM BINARY DOWNLOAD: No

CURRENT BINARY: SAMSUNG OFFICIAL

SYSTEM STATUS: Official

It froze and sometimes stopped when it was connected to my laptop. I then held both volume buttons and it went onto charging. I don't know what to do. I don't know why it said custom- I didn't tried to get a new android version or to root it.

Comment: Just flash a [factory firmware](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/database/GT-N8010/) via Odin. Nothing more you can do if that also fails.

Comment: Andy, how? I connected it to my laptop but it keeps saying installing drivers, or it disconnects momentarily.

Comment: You need to install appropriate driver (Samsung USB Driver for Mobile Phones) prior to connecting the device - the OS doesn't come with a usable driver.

Comment: Andy, my laptop won't let me do anything- it fails to install MTP

Comment: MTP isn't needed either. And if you mean your PC doesn't respond to _anything_ from the tablet - even plugging it in while under Odin mode - fine, just borrow another PC.

Comment: I've tried but Windows 7 won't let me browse my files unless the driver is installed, and on Kies 3, it disconnects after failing.

Comment: Why are you still trying to browse files / use Kies? Sort out the driver problem and use Odin to end it once and for all.

Comment: I can't download the driver which is a problem- it says my device is not compatible. How else can I flash firmware to my device?

Comment: How "not compatible"? How did you try to install the driver? Use the "Samsung USB Driver for Mobile Phones" standalone package.

Comment: Yes, I got 'Samsung USB Driver for Mobile Phones' but then a notification says MTP failed, so I found a MTP driver online, but I cant install that.

Comment: MTP is not a problem. In download mode, plug the device into the PC. As long as Odin recognizes the device as COMxx, you can start flashing.

Comment: @AndyYan sorry I just left this, but I have a new PC and Odin doesn't say any more. Not even COMxx. It doesn't change screen. I took it to a few places to repair, but what else can I do?

Comment: Driver problem? Do you see a corresponding device in Device Manager in Windows?

Comment: @AndyYan nothing.

Comment: New PC? I'm at a loss too. I'm starting to think the tablet itself has a bad USB port...

Comment: @AndyYan I tried to flash firmware via ODIN and it did as https://www.kingoapp.com/root-tutorials/how-to-flash-samsung-stock-rom-via-odin.htm  expected, but when it rebooted, it is still on bootloop. The device was recognised by ODIN

Comment: Any help @AndyYan